# Why is router.push not working? [Vue3] [Vuex4]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I have some issues with Vue 3 and Vuex.
I'm trying to redirect users when logged in in my Vuex file, but it's not working as expected.
It's not returning any errors, it's changing a link, but not redirected to another page.

My action looks like this;

```
actions: {
        async login(commit: any, payload: any ) {
            const cookie_token  = useCookies();

            API.post('/login', {
                email: payload.email.value,
                password: payload.password.value
            })
                .then((response: any) => {
                    notif.success('Welcome back, ' + response.data.player.name)
                    cookie.set('user', response.data)
                    commit.commit('loginSuccess', response.data)

                    router.push({
                      name: 'index',
                    })

                }).catch((e) => (
                    console.log(e.message)
                )
            )
        }
    },
```

And the router is getting files where routes are defined.

And here is my full router file:

```
import {
  createRouter as createClientRouter,
  createWebHistory,
} from 'vue-router'
import * as NProgress from 'nprogress'

// import routes from 'pages-generated'


import type { RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";

// Then we can define our routes
const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  // This is a simple route
  {
    component: () => import("/@src/pages/index.vue"),
    name: "index",
    path: "/",
    props: true,
  },
  {
    component: () => import("/@src/pages/auth.vue"),
    path: "/auth",
    props: true,
    children: [
      {
        component: () => import("/@src/pages/auth/login.vue"),
        name: "auth-login",
        path: "login-1",
        props: true,
      },
      {
        component: () => import("/@src/pages/auth/login.vue"),
        name: "auth-signup",
        path: "singup",
        props: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    component: () => import("/@src/pages/[...all].vue"),
    name: "404",
    path: "/:all(.*)",
    props: true,
  },
];

export function createRouter() {
  const router = createClientRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
  })

  /**
   * Handle NProgress display on-page changes
   */
  router.beforeEach(() => {
    NProgress.start()
  })
  router.afterEach(() => {
    NProgress.done()
  })

  return router
}

export default createRouter()
```

Have in mind that it's working on other files, and I can see that router is triggered here, but not chaning a page, only on vuex is not working. If it's not working, why there is no error?

Answer (score 4):

You're creating more than one instance of Vue Router. You should export the same `router` instance, not a function creating a new instance each time it gets called.

The following code will likely yield the desired outcome:

```js
import {
  createRouter,
  createWebHistory,
} from 'vue-router'
import * as NProgress from 'nprogress'
import type { RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";

const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  // your routes here...
];

let router;

export function useRouter() {
  if (!router) {
    router = createRouter({
      history: createWebHistory(),
      routes,
    })

    router.beforeEach(() => {
      NProgress.start()
    })
    router.afterEach(() => {
      NProgress.done()
    })
  }
  return router
}
```

I'm placing the `router` instance in the outer scope, so you always get the same instance when calling `useRouter()`.
Consume it using:

```
import { useRouter } from '../path/to/router'
const router = useRouter();
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that as well. Now I have error like: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/router.ts' does not provide an export named 'createRouter'

Comment: Yes, I changed the name of the function from `createRouter` to `useRouter`. Because you're not creating a new one, you're using the already created one. There's no point in naming it `createRouter`, IMHO.

Comment: Still have error Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/router.ts' does not provide an export named 'createRouter'

Comment: Somehwere in your code you have `import { createRouter } from '/src/router.ts'` (The console is telling you exactly where). Go there and replace `createRouter` with `useRouter`. Note: there might be more than one place. You have to rename the function in every place. Now, in fariness, you could keep the name of the exported function `createRouter` (and rename the imported one to `createClientRouter`, like you had before), but, in my estimation, that name would be wrong, because your function does not ***create*** a new Router instance. It returns the already created one.